# Running single class Java console applications in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Not related to actual programming, more of an IDE configuration thing. I'm trying to set up IntelliJ IDEA to run my programming competition/interview practice problems using Java console applications. I'd like to be able to just compile a single class into a Java console without making a whole Java project. Currently, I use jGrasp as it does just that, but its editor is very bare bones.
I have my JDK selected and everything, but I can't get it to run my class. This is a screenshot of my options : [image] 
Can anyone help me set this up?

Answer (score 1):

I can at least see that your `homework7.java` file is not part of the sources, this could be the issue. To fix this you need to go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources and mark your folder as sources.